# Typescript : Generic type "extract keys with value of type X" does not behave as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have defined the following generic type which extracts from a type T the string keys whose value is a number :

```
type StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string ?
    T[K] extends number ?
      K
      : never
    : never
}[keyof T];
```

I try to use this type in a generic function as following :

```
function setNumberField<T>(item: T, field: StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>): void {
  item[field] = 1;
}
```

But the line `item[field] = 1;` errors with `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>]'`.

I have tried a few different things such as narrowing the generic type T in the function to a type which explicitly contains some string keys with value number but this didn't help.

Anyone can see what the problem is ? Here is a TS playground with the code sample and some more details : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwLACgpQEMAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaXfagfhIpvqbygGMSiOgEtSAcx74AJhyq06uAL65cAelVQAgvCgQAHpD7AIU2AmABpCCB3oARATtQAPlDtS7uUJDOIrNqHQAZWARcX94AFkCYD4AC1ExADk5egAeOERkSAA+FRxvaBCwsQjo2ITxFK46DJzAzGYoAG0LKFEoAGtrAHsAM1gAXQBadig2-WNSKR0hRKhWJvwYVsHdPSmZslS6BaX8cf38DggAN3p9k-OFHEVm7pB+oYBufL7yUiNhHtIoeAhgNV5AAxYQQAA2UjqAAphMZKCQYAwoH0wZCSMVEmUYvFEkD0jAcgBKEinHrCUzYXhwiCUZqoiFSNboACMr1uQA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` in `setNumberField` is a black box. Nobody knows, even you, whether `T` has key with numeric value or not. There is not appropriate constraint. `setNumberField` allows you to provide even primitive value as a first argument. It means that inside function body, TS is unaware that `item[field]` is always a numerical value. However, TS is aware about it during function call. So function has two levels of typeings. One - is the function definition, when TS is unable to gues the `T` type and second one - during function call, when TS is aware about `T` type and able to infer it.

The easiest way to do it is to avoid mutation. You can return new object.
Consider this example:

```js
type TestType = {
  a: number,
  b?: number,
  c: string,
  d: number
}

type StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string ?
  T[K] extends number ?
  K
  : never
  : never
}[keyof T];

const setNumberField = <
  Item,
  Field extends StringKeysMatchingNumber<Item>
>(item: Item, field: Field): Item => ({
  ...item,
  [field]: 1
})

declare let foo: TestType

// {
//     a: number;
//     b: string;
// }
const result = setNumberField({ a: 42, b: 'str' }, 'a')
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEGlVm)

Please keep in mind, TypeScript does not like mutations. See my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations)

---

If you still want mutate your argument, you should overload your function.

```js
type TestType = {
  a: number,
  b?: number,
  c: string,
  d: number
}

type StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string ?
  T[K] extends number ?
  K
  : never
  : never
}[keyof T];

function setNumberField<Item, Field extends StringKeysMatchingNumber<Item>>(item: Item, field: Field): void;
function setNumberField(item: Record<string, number>, field: string): void {
  item[field] = 2
}

declare let foo: TestType

const result1 = setNumberField({ a: 42, b: 'str' }, 'a') // ok
const result2 = setNumberField({ a: 42, b: 'str' }, 'b') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZbgam)

Function overloading is not so strict. As you might have noticed, this function type definition `function setNumberField(item: Record<string, number>, field: string)` allows you to use only object where all values are numbers. But this is not the case. This is why I have overloaded this function with another one layer. The bottom one is used for function body. The top one, with `StringKeysMatchingNumber` controls function arguments.

---

**UPDATE**

> Why adding a constraint such as `T extends Record<string, number>` is
> not enough to make TS aware of the type of `item[field]`

Consider this:

```js
type StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string ?
  T[K] extends number ? // This line does not mean that T[K] is equal to number
  K
  : never
  : never
}[keyof T];
```

This line `T[K] extends number` means that `T[K]` is a subtype of number. It  can be `number & {__tag:'Batman'}`. Also, please keep in mind, that `StringKeysMatchingNumber` might return `never` and number is not assignable to `never`:

```js
declare let x: never;
x = 1 // error
```

Be aware, that calling `StringKeysMatchingNumber` with static argument like `{foo: 42}` produces expected result `"foo"`:

```js
type Result = StringKeysMatchingNumber<{ foo: 42 }> // foo
```

But resolving `StringKeysMatchingNumber` inside a function body is completely different history. Hover your mouse on `Result` inside function
See example:

```js
function setNumberField<
  T extends Record<string, number>,
  Field extends StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>
>(item: T, field: Field) {

  type Result = StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> // resolving T inside a function

  const value = item[field];

  item[field] = 1; // error
  value.toExponential // ok
}
```

`item[field]` is resolved to `T[Field]`, it is not a `number` type. It is a subtype of `number` type. Yuo are still allowed to call `toExponential`. It is very important to understand that `item[field]` is a type which has all properties of `number` type but also may contain some other properties. `number` is not primitive from TS point of view.

```js
//"toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"
type NumberKeys = keyof number
```

See this:

```js
function setNumberField<
  T extends Record<string, number>,
  Field extends StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>
>(item: T, field: Field) {
  let numSupertype = 5;
  let numSubtype = item[field]
  
  numSupertype = numSubtype // ok
  numSubtype = numSupertype // expected error
}
```

`numSubtype` is assignable to `numSupertype`. `item[field]` is assignlable to any variable with `number` type whereas `number` is not assignable to `item[field]`.

**Final question**
Is the way you want to assign a number to `item[field]` is type safe enough?

```
type StringKeysMatchingNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T];


function setNumberField<

  T extends Record<string, number>,
  Field extends StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>
>(item: T, field: Field) {
  item[field] = 2
}

type BrandNumber = number & { __tag: 'Batman' }

declare let brandNumber: BrandNumber
type WeirdDictionary = Record<string, BrandNumber>

const obj: WeirdDictionary = {
  property: brandNumber
}

setNumberField(obj, 'foo')
```

`setNumberField` expects a dictionary where each value extends `number` type. It means that value might be `number & { __tag: 'Batman' }`. I know, it is weird from developer perspective but not from type perspective. It is just a subtype of `number` and this technique is used to mock nominal types.
What happens if you assign `2` to `item[field]` without error ? After calling this function, you expect each value to be `BrandNumber` but it will not be true.

So, TypeScript does good job here :D

You can find more information about function argument inference in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints)

Comment: Great answer @captain-yossarian, thank you! And thanks for pointing me to some more resources. I definitely need to take some time and dig into the variance topic in TS.

My problem is solved but I still can't wrap my head around the following : why adding a constraint such as `T extends Record<string, number>` is not enough to make TS aware of the type of `item[field]` ? 

For example:
`function setNumberField<T extends Record<string, number>, Field extend StringKeysMatchingNumber<T>>(item: T, field: Field): void { item[field] = 1; }`

Comment: @acharp I made an update. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: Awesome @captain-yossarian, that's crystal clear, now I fully get it. Thanks again!