# PickByValue on type variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class "Storage" that stores an object and performs operations on it. Subclasses should be able to extend that variable's properties, which is why the class is generic.

Now, I want to use PickByValue (found in Utility Types, pasted below) on that generic variable, but I get a compiler error. I don't understand why:

```
export declare type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = Pick<T, {
    [Key in keyof T]-?: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never;
}[keyof T]>;

class Storage<S extends {a: string; b: number;}> {
   constructor(public store: S) {};

   printStringKey(key: keyof PickByValue<S, string>) {
       // This function should only accept keys which value is string. Should 
       // accept "a" within this class (see this.test()), might accept others in subclasses
   }

   test() {
       this.printStringKey("a"); // <- Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'S[keyof S] extends string ? keyof S : never'.
   }
}

let b = new Storage({a: "str", b: 2});
b.printStringKey("a"); // <- Works
```

I have a feeling that there is a profound thing that I'm missing here, so I hope someone can point me to it.

Comment: `PickByValue<S, string>` only resolves to a type outside the `class`, not inside it. That's just how generics work in TypeScript and any other language.

Comment: Ok, but if the function parameter was just `keyof S`, then the keys "a" and "b" would be accepted, while "c" would be denied. So, typescript knows about the keys of the generic type, but not about its values?

Comment: `keyof S` works because when being used directly, the `extends {a: string; b: number;}` constraint applies, but `S` needs to be fully resolved before being passed as a generic parameter (angle brackets) to another generic type. And it is only outside the class.

Comment: "passed as a generic parameter (angle brackets)" – I get it. Thank you. Trying to find some kind of workaround now.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `S extends {a: string; b: number;}` means that `S` might be any subtype of `{a: string; b: number;}`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3ajjw). Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494434/typescript-generic-type-extract-keys-with-value-of-type-x-does-not-behave-as/70496182#70496182) and [this article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints) might be useful