# How to throw custom Typescript compile message when checking for generic's key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am creating a custom Type that should pick a generic's `T` object keys `Key` which type of `T[Key]` is `number`.

The code works but I want to make the error message clearer.

```js
type KeysOfTypeNumber<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends number ? Key : never }[keyof T]

type Keys = {
    currentPage: number
    prevPage: number
    searchParam: string
}

const passNumberKeys = <T>(numberTypeKeys: KeysOfTypeNumber<T>) => {
    console.log(numberTypeKeys)
}

passNumberKeys<Keys>('currentPage') // OK
passNumberKeys<Keys>('searchParam') // Type '"searchParam"' is not assignable to type 'KeysOfTypeNumber<Keys>'
```

[A working code sample is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKuCA5ArgWwCMIAnAHjQD4oBeKAbygG04QoBLAOygGt4B7FFDQBdAFxDm8YVAgAPYBA4ATBFA74ixKAH5Y8KOI4QAbiSgBfRrxAChwgFD3QkPYhr17UL1ADGOYsSKwAAKAIYA5hCGGiSe3mCBxmGR0YSx3lAIEKHEPgAWYcSheOIIwMSc4fbmjj58HGVQYKEICLhpxCyqtOQUABTqHRiQXeJdqMPYMWSUAJQ0VHRxXnUNfAA2EAB063zhA9OTXbPVjs2t7ZpdpF39AOR%20AUHJEHcn523T17d9d1k5%20UKxTeQA)

Is it possible to fix my custom type so it throws something at least like `Type '"searchParam"' is not assignable to type 'Argument must be of type number inside the generic'`.

Already tried to follow [this example](https://media-codings.com/articles/throwing-custom-compile-time-errors-with-typescript), but the error remains the same.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer `Type '"searchParam"' is not assignable to type '"currentPage" | "prevPage"'` instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZbYom)?  If so, I can write up an answer.  If not, can you explain why you prefer the string literal error message?

Comment: This is not specifically what I asked, your suggestion is even more readable, I think, so yes, I would accept your answer.

EDIT: Although another answer does answer the question directly, I will have to accept that one, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494434/typescript-generic-type-extract-keys-with-value-of-type-x-does-not-behave-as/70496182#70496182) question might be helpful for you.

You can use conditional types, like here:

```js
type KeysOfTypeNumber<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends number ? Key : never }[keyof T]

type Keys = {
    currentPage: number
    prevPage: number
    searchParam: string
}

type CustomError = 'Argument must be of type number inside the generic'
const passNumberKeys = <Prop extends string>(
    numberTypeKeys: Prop extends KeysOfTypeNumber<Keys> ? Prop : CustomError
) => {
    console.log(numberTypeKeys)
}

passNumberKeys('currentPage') // OK

// Argument of type '"searchParam"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Argument must be of type number inside the generic"'
passNumberKeys('searchParam')
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8KOAW)

Please keep in mind that using explicit generic parameter `Keys` in this line `passNumberKeys<Keys>('currentPage')` which is not binded to argument is unsafe.